# How to send variable data form html to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to send variable data form html to flask
This is my html js code.
I can not send that variable data to the flask in that way.

```
<script>
        var data = "shan";
        window.location.href='{{ url_for( "move_forward" , title=data) }}';
</script>
```

But when I used below way I can send it

```
<script>
        window.location.href='{{ url_for( "move_forward" , title="shan") }}';
</script>
```

But finally I want to assign some value to the variable and I want to send it to the flask.
How can I do it

```
 @app.route("/move_forward/<title>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def move_forward(title):
             print(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

Jinja templates (the parts using `{{ ... }}`) are not JavaScript.

When you call `render_template`, `'{{ url_for( "move_forward" , title="shan") }}'` gets replaced with something like `'/move_forward/shan'` and this is what the client receives.

When you do `'{{ url_for( "move_forward" , title=data) }}'` Flask/Jinja doesn't know what `data` is because it doesn't interact with the JavaScript, it's just trying to replace a string.

You could instead use a mixture of JavaScript and Jinja to get it working:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = '{{ url_for("move_forward") }}';
    var data = "shan";
    window.location.href = baseUrl + "/" + data;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but still I can not acces the data so How can I acess the data from flask

Comment: ERR:</br>werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'move_forward'. Did you forget to specify values ['title']?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Henry for your answer and I go trough it and do little modification to do it work.

In HTML js script I modify like bellow

```
var baseUrl = '{{ url_for("move_forward") }}';
var data = "shan";
window.location.href = baseUrl + "?title=" + data;
```

and Then I modify the Flask code like bellow.

```
@app.route("/move_forward", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def move_forward():
            if request.method == 'GET':
                title = request.args.get('title')
```

Now it's work perfectly.
Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).